# WPF: Modifying a ListView's DataTemplate at runtime

Tags: .net, wpf

I need to modify my DataTemplate to add some columns to my StackPanel during runtime.

So I need a way to access the 'stackPanelLeft' and 'stackPanelRight' in my user control.

I know I could make all of the code into a long xml string and load it, but I'd like to find a way to access the stack panels from the DataTemplate and modify them this way.  Sort of a 'hybrid' approach.

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <CheckBox />
            <Image Grid.Column="1" />
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" x:Name="stackPanelLeft"/>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="3" x:Name="stackPanelRight"/>
            <Image Grid.Column="4" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

I do not know what is going to be in the stack panels.  Depending on the environment, it could be buttons, text boxes, check buttons, etc.

I've attempted to use the FindName method, but since the Visual Tree is not yet created, it only returns null.

Once I have access to the stack panel, I plan on adding controls via the FrameworkElementFactory method.

This is the approach that I was going for, but I'm open to completely alternate ideas

```
var leftPanel = FindName("stackPanelLeft");

FrameworkElementFactory control = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
textBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding(dataTable.ColumnName));
leftPanel.AppendChild(textBlock);
```

Comment: Your approach is far from ideal. if you need to dynamically define UI "parts" or such. Create a Proper ViewModel and use `ContentPresenter`s and `DataTemplate`s to dynamically show them. Manipulating UI elements inside a `DataTemplate` in procedural code is the worst idea ever.

Comment: As much as I agree with you, this is unfortunately a requirement for my project.  A user is adding the names, colors, and type of fields in another app, and my job is to display their data in a specific format.

I have all of this written already in code-behind and it is already working well.  I was hoping to move much of the FrameworkElementFactory code into xaml, and only supply the list of controls that they want to display in code-behind.

Comment: doing things wrong is never a requirement. If you get DATA from elsewhere, create proper DATATemplates to display your DATA. Even if the DATA represents UI "parts", it's still DATA. and DATA is not UI. and UI is not DATA. My point still stands, while you CAN do this, `manipulating UI Elements [inside a DataTemplate] in procedural code is the worst idea ever.`

Comment: Instead of a `StackPanel`, put an `ItemControl` in there, and bind it's `ItemsSource` property to some collection of these Items, and then create specific `DataTemplate`s for each item type so that you can get many different "UI Parts" with different content, all defined by the Data you're recieving, without resorting to horrible procedural approaches.

Comment: Then help me find a better solution.  If the data table contains two columns, I need to add two columns to the left stack panel and bind to it.  How would you suggest I do that during runtime?

Comment: Build a custom control with dependency properties for the content slots. The properties should be typed `object` so a user can choose whether to insert their own controls directly or insert data to be presented by a DataTemplate. Define a default style for the control, with a ControlTemplate that contains, for each content slot property, a ContentPresenter whose ContentSource is set to the property name.

Comment: ... Unless there is an arbitrary amount of "slots", then use an ItemsControl.

Comment: How about instead of `StackPanel`'s you just have `ContentPresenter`'s and bind their content to whatever you want (could be a dynamically created `StackPanel` with all your stuff in it).

Comment: I think I'll go with HighCore/nmclean's idea and make two custom controls for the two slots.  That way, I can still have my UserControl with the layout, then only include the code-behind code for the stack panels.  That should provide me with the 'hybrid' that I require.  Thanks!